# Spring Boot deployment on WLP (WebSphere Liberty) throws CWWKC0044W error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, websphere, websphere-liberty

I have a *Spring Boot* application which runs fine via either *Spring Boot Gradle Plugin*, or `java -jar myApp.war` command.

However, I receive following error if I try to deploy it on the *WebSphere Liberty* application server:

```
[WARNING ] CWWKC0044W: An exception occurred while scanning class and annotation data. The exception was java.lang.RuntimeException
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitModule(ClassVisitor.java:148)
        at [internal classes]
.
```

<del>Moreover, this error causes that *Spring Boot* starts to log with the `DEBUG` severity even if it's configured with `INFO`, or `WARN`.</del>

Can someone direct me toward the root cause, or how to investigate deeper?

I'm using following versions:

- Spring Boot: 2.0.0.M7
- WLP: 17.0.0.4
- Java (build): Zulu 1.8.0_152
- Java (WLP): IBM 8.0.5.6

and following dependencies:

```java
dependencies {
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.0.0.M7"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:2.0.0.M7"

    providedRuntime "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:2.0.0.M7"
}
```

<del>I tried different versions of *Spring Boot* (1.5.9) and *WLP* (17.0.0.3), but the error haven't changed.</del>

---

**Update**: The error is not present in *Spring Boot* 1.5.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get rid of the error by exclusion of the *Log4j* transitive dependency. It was necessary to remove it from every `spring-boot-starter-*` dependency (`web` and `thymeleaf` in my case). Therefore, I've excluded it on the global level:

```java
configurations {
    implementation {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j'
    }
}
```

I'm using *Gradle* 4, so the configuration is `implementation`. It should be `compile` for older versions.

However, I still don't know what was the root cause, so some explanation would be nice. I suspect some older/incompatible versions of Java.

Comment: Could you please add your server.xml configuration I have the same problem

Comment: Unfortunately, it was my past employment, so that time configuration is not available for me anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be include the Liberty spring boot starter, and exclude the Tomcat starter (since you're using Liberty instead of Tomcat).

Your dependencies should look something like this:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  // Include liberty and exclude tomcat
  compile('io.openliberty.boot:liberty-spring-boot-starter:0.5.0.M1')
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') {
    exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
  }
  ...
}
```

For a more detailed walkthrough of a basic HelloServlet with Liberty+Spring, check out Tom Watson's blog post: [Open Liberty Spring Boot Starter](https://openliberty.io/news/2017/11/29/liberty-spring-boot.html)

Comment: `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` is already effectively excluded via  `providedRuntime` - it's not present in the deployed WAR.

Comment: Nope, adding of `liberty-spring-boot-starter` doesn't change a thing. Still, the same error.